# NtCreateProcess(Ex) - Can I have a child process inherit the parents address space while running under a different process name?

Tags: windows, process, native

I am calling NtCreateProcessEx with the section handle argument set to NULL in order to create a user mode process that is initialized with a copy of the parents address space.

I want the child process to run under a different image name other than the one of the parent process.

Is this even possible?

Here's my call to NtCreateProcessEx:

```
HANDLE fileHandle;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes = { 0 };

UNICODE_STRING InputString;

RtlInitUnicodeString( &InputString, L"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\codeblocks_projects\\test\\bin\\Release\\test.exe" );

ObjectAttributes.Length = sizeof( OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES );
ObjectAttributes.ObjectName = &InputString;

NTSTATUS status = NtCreateProcessEx( &fileHandle, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, &ObjectAttributes, GetCurrentProcess(), PS_INHERIT_HANDLES, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE );

printf_s( "%x\n", status );
```

Status is 0xC0000033 - STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID, if I don't pass any object attributes, the call works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: windows simply not implemented name for process object. as result if you use name in `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` you and got `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID`. also name like `"C:\\.."` is invalid too - if you pass it to object which allow naming - you got `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_SYNTAX_BAD`

Comment: So, is it possible to change the process name of a forked process at all? Doesn't sound like it.

Comment: no, impossible. name is from image file. not from process object itself

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: use fork for windows is possible, but very unusual and undocumented. and after you create process this way - you still need create threads in it. then this process not connected to csrss, as result what you can do inside it very restricted

Comment: i dont really want to fork, I just need a second process with duplicated address space. :-)

Comment: but this is what i mean under fork. but this process will be not full functional win32 process

Comment: thats not a problem - I dont want it to run, I dont need any functionality, just a second process with duplicated address space.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this not only poorly documented; it is also impossible. At least, it seems effectively impossible nowadays, perhaps due to security concerns.

The documentation for NtOpenProcess indicates that even *identifying* a process by name hasn't been possible since Vista:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-ntopenprocess

I just tried an alternative approach using NtSetInformationProcess:

```
#define PHNT_NO_INLINE_INIT_STRING
#include <phnt_windows.h>
#include <phnt.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    NTSTATUS status;
    HANDLE handle;

    status
        = NtCreateProcess(&handle,
                          PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
                          NULL,
                          NtCurrentProcess(),
                          /*InheritObjectTable=*/TRUE,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          NULL
            );

    UNICODE_STRING newName;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&newName, L"dummy.exe");

    status
        = NtSetInformationProcess(
            handle,
            ProcessImageFileName,
            &newName,
            sizeof newName
            );
    // fails with 0xC0000003, STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS
    printf("status: %x\n", status);

    // pause to observe the new "zombie child" in Process Explorer
    printf("sleeping...\n");
    Sleep(5000);
    
    return 0;
}
```

As noted in the code, NtSetInformationProcess fails with STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS, even though this is allowed by the corresponding NtQueryInformationProcess:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess

Looking at the ReactOS source, this seems to be a deliberate omission. I also found this:

https://reactos.org/pipermail/ros-diffs/2004-November/002066.html

As of this writing, the above reads "don't allow the ProcessImageFileName information class for NtSetInformationProcess() anymore".

All this suggests it *may* have been possible in the past. After all, how was exec() in the old POSIX subsystem implemented? After fork() created an initial thread in the new process and set the thread's context to be a copy of the parent's, the child might then call exec(), whereupon the POSIX implementation probably destroyed and re-created the child process from within. At some point, the subsystem would have to set the ProcessImageFileName *somehow*.