# Calling NtCreateProcessEx fails without exception

Tags: c++, winapi, system-calls, ntdll

I want to call `NtCreateProcessEx`, But i get no exception and error and nothing happens. Also i don't want to use `CreateProcess`. My intention is to create and run a process from a file with this specific function.

This what i have tried so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>
#include "winternl.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll")

NTSTATUS NTAPI NtCreateProcessEx(
    OUT HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    IN OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes OPTIONAL,
    IN HANDLE ParentProcess,
    IN BOOLEAN InheritObjectTable,
    IN HANDLE SectionHandle OPTIONAL,
    IN HANDLE DebugPort OPTIONAL,
    IN HANDLE ExceptionPort OPTIONAL,
    IN BOOLEAN InJob);

int main()
{
    const HANDLE ph = nullptr;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa;
    UNICODE_STRING fileName;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&fileName, PCWSTR(L"\\??\\C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe"));
    (&oa)->Length = sizeof(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES);
    (&oa)->RootDirectory = nullptr;
    (&oa)->Attributes = 0x00000040L;
    (&oa)->ObjectName = &fileName;
    (&oa)->SecurityDescriptor = nullptr;
    (&oa)->SecurityQualityOfService = nullptr;;
    NtCreateProcessEx(ph, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, oa, nullptr, FALSE, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE);

    return 0;
}
```

There is no document and example on whole internet about this specific function. I am able to do something somewhat similar to this for `NtCreateFile`, But this is my closest try for `NtCreateProcessEx` and no luck.

I work with Visual Studio 2019 and windows 10 1909.

These are some resources that i  tried:

1. [NtCreateProcess(Ex) - Can I have a child process inherit the parents address space while running under a different process name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457259/ntcreateprocessex-can-i-have-a-child-process-inherit-the-parents-address-spa)
2. http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40191-ntcreateuserprocess/
3. https://github.com/Microwave89/createuserprocess/blob/master/createuserprocess/main.c
4. http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/42229-start-a-process-using-ntcreateprocessex-usermode/
5. https://hshrzd.wordpress.com/2017/12/18/process-doppelganging-a-new-way-to-impersonate-a-process/

Comment: you wrong use `NtCreateProcessEx`. `ObjectAttributes` must not point to any file. and must be 0. instead you need create section from executable file and pass it in place `SectionHandle`. also need do much more job - create thread in process, attach process to *csrss*, allocate environment vars, etc. `CreateProcess` do all this.

Comment: @RbMm So i cannot just call `NtCreateProcessEx` and i have to redefine it. But i wonder why `NtCreateFile` is much easier to work with. Do u have any example or resource to help me accomplish this?

Comment: If it isn't documented why are you using it?

Comment: @user207421 It is not documented but not illegal (just no support). Experimenting with undocumented Api is a common thing in some online courses and in quarantine days :) . Also u should blame many thousand of developers for knowing about an undocumented function.

Comment: You can research this fine. I'd start by finding source code online that calls it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the 3rd parameter is a pointer to the `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`:

```
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* fpNtCreateProcessEx)
(
    PHANDLE     ProcessHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK  DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes  OPTIONAL,
    HANDLE   ParentProcess,
    ULONG    Flags,
    HANDLE SectionHandle     OPTIONAL,
    HANDLE DebugPort     OPTIONAL,
    HANDLE ExceptionPort     OPTIONAL,
    BOOLEAN  InJob
    );
```

A sample to use(remove error checking):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define NtCurrentProcess() ( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -1 )
typedef struct _LSA_UNICODE_STRING {
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR  Buffer;
} LSA_UNICODE_STRING, * PLSA_UNICODE_STRING, UNICODE_STRING, * PUNICODE_STRING;


typedef struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {
    ULONG           Length;
    HANDLE          RootDirectory;
    PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    ULONG           Attributes;
    PVOID           SecurityDescriptor;
    PVOID           SecurityQualityOfService;
}  OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, * POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;


typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* fpNtCreateProcessEx)
(
    PHANDLE     ProcessHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK  DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes  OPTIONAL,
    HANDLE   ParentProcess,
    ULONG    Flags,
    HANDLE SectionHandle     OPTIONAL,
    HANDLE DebugPort     OPTIONAL,
    HANDLE ExceptionPort     OPTIONAL,
    BOOLEAN  InJob
);

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* fpNtCreateTransaction)
(
    PHANDLE            TransactionHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    LPGUID             Uow,
    HANDLE             TmHandle,
    ULONG              CreateOptions,
    ULONG              IsolationLevel,
    ULONG              IsolationFlags,
    PLARGE_INTEGER     Timeout,
    PUNICODE_STRING    Description
);

typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *fpNtCreateSection)
(
    PHANDLE SectionHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    PLARGE_INTEGER MaximumSize,
    ULONG SectionPageProtection,
    ULONG AllocationAttributes,
    HANDLE FileHandle
);
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *fpNtClose)
(
    HANDLE Handle
);
#define PS_INHERIT_HANDLES                      4

int main()
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objattr;
    UNICODE_STRING objname;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR wstrObjName[MAX_PATH];
    lstrcpyW(wstrObjName, L"C:\\test.exe");

    HINSTANCE hinst = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
    fpNtCreateProcessEx _NtCreateProcessEx = (fpNtCreateProcessEx)GetProcAddress(hinst, "NtCreateProcessEx");
    fpNtCreateTransaction _NtCreateTransaction = (fpNtCreateTransaction)GetProcAddress(hinst, "NtCreateTransaction");
    fpNtCreateSection _NtCreateSection = (fpNtCreateSection)GetProcAddress(hinst, "NtCreateSection");
    fpNtClose _NtClose = (fpNtClose)GetProcAddress(hinst, "NtClose");

    // Initialize ObjectName UNICODE_STRING
    objname.Buffer = wstrObjName;
    objname.Length = wcslen(wstrObjName) * sizeof(WCHAR); // Length in bytes of string, without null terminator
    objname.MaximumLength = MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR);


    // Initialize OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
    objattr.Length = sizeof(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES);
    objattr.Attributes = 0x00000040L; //OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE 
    objattr.ObjectName = NULL;
    objattr.RootDirectory = NULL;
    objattr.SecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    objattr.SecurityQualityOfService = NULL;


    HANDLE hTransaction = NULL;
    status = _NtCreateTransaction(&hTransaction,
        TRANSACTION_ALL_ACCESS,
        &objattr,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    HANDLE hTransactedFile = CreateFileTransacted(wstrObjName,
        GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL,
        hTransaction,
        NULL,
        NULL);
    HANDLE hSection = NULL;
    status = _NtCreateSection(&hSection,
        SECTION_ALL_ACCESS,
        NULL,
        0,
        PAGE_READONLY,
        SEC_IMAGE,
        hTransactedFile);

    status = _NtCreateProcessEx(&hProcess, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, NtCurrentProcess(), PS_INHERIT_HANDLES, hSection, NULL, NULL, false);
    DWORD pid = GetProcessId(hProcess);
    printf("Pid = %d\n", pid);

    CloseHandle(hTransactedFile);
    _NtClose(hTransaction);
    _NtClose(hSection);
    _NtClose(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is GREAT, Just one question: The process get created in `suspended` state so no cpu time, Do i have to change a specific flag or use another standard function to resume the process state?